# rvmsudo command not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to get an updated version of a RoR environment.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, and I have this setup:

```
$ groups
user adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare rvm
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.17.2 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem -v
1.8.24
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.9
```

All work fine. But now I am trying to install Thin and I found out that my rvmsudo command in pretty much useless:

```
$ rvmsudo echo 1
1
$ rvmsudo ruby -v
sudo: ruby: command not found
$ rvmsudo gem -v
sudo: gem: command not found
$ rvmsudo rails -v
sudo: rails: command not found
```

The same error when I run "rvmsudo thin install".

I am completely stuck. In Ubuntu 10.04 it worked fine and even my first test in 12.04 I got rvmsudo working perfect. I followed the exact same steps this time, but nothing seems to work.

I installed RVM using "curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable", I added myself to the rvm group, restarted the machine, used "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh" and installed my stuff normally.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any differences in the output of `echo $PATH` vs `rvmsudo echo $PATH`?

Comment: I had something like that.. http://superuser.com/questions/376669/why-am-i-getting-rvm-command-not-found-on-ubuntu

Comment: Justin, they are exactly the same: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails329/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: David, I tried that bash curl command, it messed even more my rvm, but then I echoed the path to ~/.rvm and used `rvm reload`. Then I got a secure_path problem every time I try to run rvmsudo. It says to `export rvmsudo_secure_path=1`. Now I am trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working.

I saw [this serverfault page](https://serverfault.com/questions/452907/how-do-you-configure-rvmsudo-using-chef) and I thought the problem was similar, so I gave it a try.

It seems there is something broken in version 1.17 of RVM. I installed a previous version using the command:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s -- --version 1.16.13
```

But note that RVM 1.17 installs ruby-1.9.3-p327 and RVM 1.16.13 installs ruby-1.9.3-p286.

Updating from 1.16.13 doesn't work either, so lets hope they fix it soon.

Comment: did you gave a try master version: `rvm get head`?

Comment: Yes, mpapis, same issues. Cheers.

Comment: I see you mention `export rvmsudo_secure_path=1` - did you set it?

Answer (score 3):

Add `export rvmsudo_secure_path=1` at the very end of your `~/.bashrc` file and restart your Terminal.

This worked for me *(Ubuntu 12.10 running bash)*

Answer (score 2):

It is because the secure_path option has been set in your `/etc/sudoers` and the option's value is different to your current shell `$PATH`.

Solutions:

1. Add the following command to your shell init script (for bash sell it is .bashrc for *nix, and .bash_profile for mac os x)

   ```
   export rvmsudo_secure_path=0  # means don't use the value in rvmsudo
   ```
2. add rvm and Ruby's paths to the `secure_path` value.

From my point of view, the first is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's been fixed in the latest 1.18.x versions. I upgraded to version 1.18.5 and this issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem after update rvm and ruby, and rvmsudo_secure_path=1 helps me, as was described in http://www.snowcrash.eu/rvmsudo_secure_path/